# Need help comparing Strings with different sizes

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I have two strings and they have different sizes

**GetLocalCit** returns the name of the city where each citizen lives

**GetLocalNurse** returns the name of the city where each Nurse works with a CS before it.

```
GetLocalCit=$(awk -F "[:]" '{print $4}' citizens.txt)
GetLocalNurse=$(awk -F "[:]" '{print $3}' nurses.txt)
```

Output of **GetLocalCit** is:

```
Lisboa
Santarem
Porto
Porto
Lisboa
Braga
Braganca
Setubal
Setubal
Porto
Leiria
Santarem
Porto
Lisboa
```

Output of **GetLocalNurse** is:

```
CSLisboa
CSPorto
CSSantarem
CSSetubal
CSLeiria
CSBraga
CSBraganca
CSBeja
CSEvora
CSFaro
 CSCoina 
 CSMarvao 
CSTrasOM
CSTrs
CSAA
CSAB
CSAC
CSAD
CSAE
CSAF
```

What I want to do is compare each **different** city name from **GetLocalCit** with every city name in **GetLocalNurse** and IF I find a match (aka if a city´s name is already inside **GetLocalNurse**), then I want to echo "There is a nurse in this city".

I looked this up online and tried to implement a variation of this

```
#!/bin/bash

STR='GNU/Linux is an operating system'
SUB='Linux'
if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
  echo "It's there."
fi
```

in my code, but it probably doesn´t work because there are multiple words with separated by '\n' in both strings...

I also thought about creating a **WHILE** cycle but don´t know how to properly implement it with strings!

Comment: You can *probably* do the whole thing in awk, without intermediate files: `awk -F ':' 'NR==FNR{nurses[$3]; next} !seen[$4]++ && ("CS" $4 in nurses) {print "There is a nurse in this city: " $4}' nurses.txt citizens.txt` (not posting as an answer since I can't test it without samples of the original files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are better off using `grep` and **GetLocalCit** as list of search strings:

```
 grep -f GetLocalCit GetLocalNurse
```

Or if they are commands rather than files

```
 grep -f <(GetLocalCit)  <(GetLocalNurse)
```

It will return the following:

```
CSLisboa
CSPorto
CSSantarem
CSSetubal
CSLeiria
CSBraga
CSBraganca
```

You could then play with this list e.g. via sed:

```
grep -f GetLocalCit GetLocalNurse | sed 's/CS/There is already a nurse in /'
```

To end up with:

```
There is already a nurse in Lisboa
There is already a nurse in Porto
There is already a nurse in Santarem
There is already a nurse in Setubal
There is already a nurse in Leiria
There is already a nurse in Braga
There is already a nurse in Braganca
```

Note how this cancels repeating cities in **GetLocalCit**

---

Now for the original code sample:

You would need to loop over the two lists, I'll assume them to be files here:

```
for city in $(cat GetLocalCit) ; do
  for nurse in $(cat GetLocalNurse) ; do
    if [[ $nurse =~ $city ]] ; then
       echo "Nurse found in $city."
    fi
  done
done
```

Probably not very effective using nested `bash` loops.

```
Nurse found in Lisboa.
Nurse found in Santarem.
Nurse found in Porto.
Nurse found in Porto.
Nurse found in Lisboa.
Nurse found in Braga.
Nurse found in Braga.
Nurse found in Braganca.
Nurse found in Setubal.
Nurse found in Setubal.
Nurse found in Porto.
Nurse found in Leiria.
Nurse found in Santarem.
Nurse found in Porto.
Nurse found in Lisboa.
```

All repetitions maintained.

Answer (score 1):

```
comm -12 <(GetLocalCit | sort -u) <(GetLocalNurse | cut -c3- | sort -u) |
    sed -E 's/^/There is a nurse in /'

There is a nurse in Braga
There is a nurse in Braganca
There is a nurse in Leiria
There is a nurse in Lisboa
There is a nurse in Porto
There is a nurse in Santarem
There is a nurse in Setubal
```

This uses `comm` to identify common lines in a pair of sorted files